# Low performance and timeout with my rest API

Tags: php, sql, performance, api, rest

I am hosting a restful API created using Silex (a PHP micro-framework based on Symfony). Following [this tutorial](http://olegpuzanov.com/2014/12/19/exposing-data-via-restful-json-api-with-silex-in-10-minutes/), this API returns json objects depending on the parameters. However some queries are so low that OVH's timeout kicks in and I get the following message :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Although some of my SQL queries are a bit long (up to 8-12 lines), they aren't that complex and I don't understand why the performance is that low.

Is there anything I can do to speed it up, and to avoid being timed out by OVH ?
I am querying every items using solely one SQL request (thus being long sometimes), and various operators (WHERE, several AND/OR, IN...).

Here's an example of a SQL query which takes forever to get :

```
SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE staff_id IN (
        SELECT host_id
        FROM class_host
        WHERE class_id IN (
                SELECT class_id
                FROM class
                WHERE classroom_id IN (
                        SELECT classroom_id
                        FROM classroom
                        WHERE classroom_gps_lat BETWEEN $ARRAY_VALEUR [0]
                                AND $ARRAY_VALEUR [2]
                            AND classroom_gps_lon BETWEEN $ARRAY_VALEUR [1]
                                AND $ARRAY_VALEUR [3]
                        )
                )
        )
    OR staff_id IN (
        SELECT teacher_id
        FROM class_teacher
        WHERE class_id IN (
                SELECT class_id
                FROM class
                WHERE classroom_id IN (
                        SELECT classroom_id
                        FROM classroom
                        WHERE classroom_gps_lat BETWEEN $ARRAY_VALEUR [0]
                                AND $ARRAY_VALEUR [2]
                            AND classroom_gps_lon BETWEEN $ARRAY_VALEUR [1]
                                AND $ARRAY_VALEUR [3]
                        )
                )
        )
    AND class_id IN (
        SELECT class_id
        FROM class_teacher
        WHERE teacher_id IN (
                SELECT staff_id
                FROM staff
                WHERE staff_name LIKE $QUOTEDARRAY
                )
        )
```

Still having performance issues. My code went from this :

```
SELECT Count(*) AS COUNT 
FROM   staff 
WHERE  staff_id IN (SELECT host_id 
                    FROM   class_host 
                    WHERE  ( class_id IN (SELECT class_id 
                                          FROM   class 
                                          WHERE  classroom_id IN (SELECT 
                                                 classroom_id 
                                                                  FROM 
                                                 classroom 
                                                                  WHERE 
                                                 region_id IN ( 'FR' ))) ) 
                            OR staff_id IN (SELECT teacher_id 
                                            FROM   class_teacher 
                                            WHERE  class_id IN (SELECT class_id 
                                                                FROM   class 
                                                                WHERE 
                                                   classroom_id IN (SELECT 
                                                   classroom_id 
                                                                    FROM 
                                                   classroom 
                                                                    WHERE 
                                                   region_id IN (SELECT 
                                                   region_id 
                                                                 FROM   region 
                                                                 WHERE 
                                                   region_country_code IN ( 
                                                   'FR' ))))))
```

to this :

```
SELECT Count(*) AS COUNT 
FROM   staff 
       JOIN class_host 
         ON staff.staff_id = class_host.host_id 
       JOIN class AS class1 
         ON class_host.class_id = class1.class_id 
       JOIN classroom AS classroom1 
         ON class1.classroom_id = classroom1.classroom_id 
       JOIN region AS region1 
         ON classroom1.region_id = region1.region_id 
       JOIN class_teacher 
         ON staff.staff_id = class_teacher.teacher_id 
       JOIN class AS class2 
         ON class_teacher.class_id = class2.class_id 
       JOIN classroom AS classroom2 
         ON class2.classroom_id = classroom2.classroom_id 
       JOIN region AS region2 
         ON classroom2.region_id = region2.region_id 
WHERE  region1.region_country_code IN ( 'FR' ) 
       AND region2.region_country_code IN ( 'FR' )
```

Should I use "faster" joins ? How can I optimize those queries ?

EDIT : EXPLAIN array from MySQL :

[Explain from MySQL database for the query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pebY3.jpg)

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but for the love of biscuits, please *format your queries!*  For both your own sanity and ours.

Comment: Please research `JOIN`s.  There is really no need for all the sub-queries you have in your query.

Comment: Will do in the future @Siyual !
Also JOIN it is then, thank you. I'll modify my queries and see how it goes. Not sure how to accept your answer as it is actually a comment instead of an actual answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started cleaning this up - Please note query is incomplete. This should be faster because you are not nesting selects.

```
SELECT
    staff.*
FROM 
    staff
    JOIN class_host ON staff.staff_id = class_host.host_id
    JOIN class ON class_host.class_id = class.class_id
    JOIN classroom ON classroom.classroom_id = class.classroom_id
WHERE
    classroom.gps_lat BETWEEN $ARRAY_VALEUR[0] AND $ARRAY_VALEUR[2]
    AND classroom.classroom_gps_lon BETWEEN $ARRAY_VALEUR[1] AND $ARRAY_VALEUR[3];
```

Once you have completed with joins - use Explain. `EXPLAIN SELECT staff.* FROM ...` which will help you to see where the query is running slow because chances are you are missing some indexes.

Comment: Thank you, I still have a lot to learn about SQL structure. I didn't think about nesting select and was just concatenating queries. I'll try this out and see if the performance increases

Comment: Take a look at this for explanation of what an `inner join` is. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: I'm still having performance issues ; editing top post to profit from code formatting, I'm not sure if I'm doing joins right

Comment: Can you put `EXPLAIN` before your select into your sql client and provide the resulting table please?

Comment: Added EXPLAIN screenshot for the query above. This query takes more than 10 seconds thus gets timed out by OVH

Comment: So your tables do not have any indexes. In mysql - you will need to add indexes to your primary keys and also your foreign keys.

Comment: Unfortunately this database isn't mine. I'll look into indexing, thank you !